# Google Map does not display the whole map

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I have a problem with google map..the case is, it will not load the whole map but only a part of the map and the rest it's blank already..what could be the problem?..

here's the code..

```
<div id="map_addresses" class="map">
    <p>This will be replaced with the Google Map.</p>
</div>


$(function()
{

   $('#map_addresses').gMap({
        controls: {
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
    },
        scrollwheel: true,
        zoom: 5,
         maptype: 'ROADMAP',
        markers:[
            {
                latitude: 10.318577,
                longitude: 123.908062,
                html: "Jinisys Software Inc. Sales Office"
            },
            {
                latitude: 10.324213,
                longitude: 123.911546,
                html: "Jinisys Software Inc. Main Office"
            }

        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the css for the page, is the map_addresses div big enough for the map?

Comment: I'll bet you're trying to load this map into a hidden element.

Comment: no, the size of the map just fit the page..the problem is it will only show a part of the map.

Comment: @sparky - yes. it's container should only be seen if i click a certain button..i used a toggle slide effect

Comment: it's kinda funny coz when i open my firebug the map seems to load the whole map content but if i refreshed it again it disappears

Comment: This is a known issue.  You must load map when the element is revealed.  It cannot be preloaded into hidden element.

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781832/google-maps-api-3-is-acting-buggy/13781905#13781905

Answer (score 2):

Google map can only be loaded on to a visible `div`. Also, the `width` and `height` of the element have to be fixed. The map won't resize the div.

Try this:

```
<style>
    .map{
        width:400px;
        height:400px;
    }
</style>

<div id="map_addresses" class="map">
    <p>This will be replaced with the Google Map.</p>
</div>
```